# How to show mysql tables in one line?

Tags: mysql

Show tables lists a formatted output.

```
+----------------------------+
|           Tables           |
+----------------------------+
| table1                     |
| table2                     |
| table3                     |
+----------------------------+
```

How do I make the output like "table1, table2, table3, ..." ?

Comment: do you mean in mysql?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(table_name)
FROM information_schema.tables
```